# Default Folder for Terminal in OSX, When Running Python Interactive Shell

Tags: python

This is a follow up question as I'm trying to move forward with Zelle's Python:Programming.

It appears that IDLE 2.7.2 has hang issues when opening graphics windows in interactive mode. But, I can simply run Python interactively in Terminal and don't have any of those issues. So that's a big help. Zelle provides a simplified graphics file called graphics.py, to get up to speed with objects and graphics, before dealing directly with Tkinter.

My question is this. Where should I put graphics.py, so Terminal will see it (when it's called), without including the full path every time? Thanks,

Henry

Answer (score 2):

According to [PEP 0370](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/), a good place to put your user packages is in `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

Modules in here should be importable.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `~/.bashrc` to include a `PYTHONPATH` definition that includes the location of the file.

```
export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/directory_containing_graphics.py"
```

Just be careful if it's in your home director to use `/Users/[username]/etc/directory_containing_graphics.py`, I vaguely recall being bitten by `~` not expanding like I expected one time on OS X.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I put the file into /Library/Frameworks/2.7/lib/python2.7 and that seemed to work. Am I better off doing that? I assume I put that export command directly into Terminal? If so, can use it anytime I create a new directory I'm keeping my files in?

Comment: If you put the export command into the terminal you'll have to do it every single time. If you edit (or create) a file called `.bashrc` (the dot is important) in your home directory, the commands in there will be executed automatically every time Terminal opens (assuming you're using Bash as your shell). I think it's neater to keep personal scripts and libraries somewhere under my home directory and use PYTHONPATH like this, it also means they persist across different Python versions, but it's a personal choice. You can add as many directories as you like, separated by colons.

Comment: Wow, I'm such a newbie. I agree, it would be great to be able to tell Bash (yes that's what I'm using) where to find my programs. Right now, I just keep stuff in Documents and I'd like to create a folder that hold all my programs. So I created .bashrc file and put it in /users/<myname>/ directory and even figured out how to see it and edit it. I then put export PYTHONPATH="/users/<myname>/Documents/<filename>" just to test this. I then restarted Terminal. I tried running the file directly from the $ promt, no luck. Then I tried to run it using the full path. And it worked. Ideas?

Comment: Yep, my bad - the PYTHONPATH should point to the directory the files are in, not the files themselves - give it another try without /<filename> and see what happens. I'll modify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I went deep down the rabbit hole to get to bottom of this issue. It turns out that bash on OSX has a few quirks, not unexpected with the various flavors of UNIX around. It turns out that when firing up a bash shell, bash looks in `.bash_profile` for config statements. If you enter bash into bash, you fire up a sub shell, and that's when and only when `.bashrc` is executed.

To make sure you only have to manage one config file, put:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

in your `.bash_profile`. This just tells bash to look into the `.bashrc` file if it exists. You can then leave that file alone and only modify your `.bashrc` file and all instances of bash will be modified the same. Once I figured this out, I still had to solve my problem. Here's the best I could do. When Python installed it installed this into my .bash_profile:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

This tells bash where to look for the libraries needed to run Python. So I moved this statement to my `.bashrc` file after putting the "if" statement into my `.bash_profile`. I then tried adding a : to the PATH statement with the path to my Python modules, but that didn't work. So, I have settled for a statement like this in .bashrc:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/ftpbub/Documents/workspace/Python\ Programming\ Modules/src/
export PYTHONPATH
```

Now I enter `python` at the command prompt, and when I get to python, I can enter `import modulename` without the path and it works. If I start a new project in a new directory, I should be able to add it to my `PYTHONPATH` and be good. I would have liked to be able to enter `python modulename` right into bash and have the module execute, but I haven't figured out how to do that. Other than that, I think this the best I can do. Ideas for how to go straight to the module from the bash prompt, without entering the path?